# Janus GridEX.AddingRecord - Access Values

Tags: winforms, janus

The GridEX.AddingRecord is the obvious hook for validation but I can't work out how to access the values entered into the new row cells?

My grid is bound to a DTO.  _grid.GetRow().DataRow returns DTO with none of the properties set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following code to access cell values in the AddingRecord event:

```
object value = grid.GetRow().Cells["ColumnName"].Value;
```

Where "ColumnName" is the Column Key in Grid's properties.

Off course you have to cast the value returned to the data type you are expecting from this field.